# Buying an apartment in France

Tags: real-estate, france

Can anyone list the costs included when buying a flat in France aside from the price tag for non-citizen? I am not a French citizen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a french or non-french resident, the main extra cost for buying real estate in France are taxes and notary fees, usually just called altogether "frais de notaire".

- For an existing property, they usually represent about 7% of the price tag, entirely payed by the buyer. (Notaries often remove the seller agent fees from the price tag for a lower calculation basis). It depends a little on the location of the property, but some websites offer simple estimation forms (like this one: http://www.pap.fr/argent/calculettes/frais-de-notaire). It is often a little bit overestimated, but it shouldn't be more than that.
- For a new property, they represent about 2% of the price tag.

You can ask an property hunter to look for a place for you, and if you do you will have to pay him too of course.

If the seller has used a real-estate agent to find the buyer, the fees are included in the price tag. (FYI it usually represents 4 to 5%, but can be down to 2% with some "low-cost" agencies.)

This is about it for one-time costs. 
Once you have bought the place, do not forget taxes:

- "Taxe foncière" (local property tax, highly location-dependent - ask the seller for how much he paid last year)
- "Taxe d'habitation" (another local tax you pay if you personnaly use the place, even very occasionaly) or "Taxe sur les logements vacants" (this is also a local tax you pay in big cities with a high housing demand if the place is unoccupied). This is usually about the same order of magnitude as the property tax.
- If you rent the place and generate income, you must also pay income tax in France.